# How to parse JSON without root key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I tried searching but couldn't find any proper solution for this. I am trying to parse JSON using the RestClient gem in Ruby without a root key. When I parse it, it returns blank values.

This is the sample JSON I am trying to parse.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
]
```

I get the proper output, but when I try to access specific fields, I get blank output:

```
require 'rest-client'

output = RestClient.get 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
puts output

puts output[0]["username"]
```

I get no output for username.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but try using `p` instead of `puts` for debug output.  `p` shows the "inspect" format for what it is printing, which can be more useful.

Comment: Thanks @WayneConrad I will use this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rest-client` does not parse the JSON itself. You need to do this as an explicit step:

```
require 'rest-client'

response = RestClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
output = JSON.parse(response.body) # or just JSON.parse(response) would also work

puts output[0]["username"]
```

Comment: Separation of concerns: There are many different data formats used in the web: JSON, HTML, CSV, XML, TXT - just to name same. IMHO it doesn't make much sense including parsers for each of them into a tool like `RestClient`.